# Java client/server calculator not working

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to create a simple calculator using sockets but when I send numbers to the server I have a problem: for example if I want to add 2 numbers x=13 and y=2 the server receives x=64 and y=42 and the result is 106. I think that the problem is with the method write, I have no problem with strings but with numbers I dont know how to work. I'm a beginner, thanks for the help.

SERVER

```
    package calcolatrice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket msocket;
    BufferedReader in;
    DataOutputStream out;
    public Socket attendi() {
        try {
            //creo il server sulla porta ****
            System.out.println("Server in esecuzione..");
            server = new ServerSocket(1122);

            //accetto eventuale connessione da parte del client
            msocket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connesso con successo! ");

            //chiudo la connessione per evitare altre connessioni
            server.close();

            //inizializzo gli stream per consentire la comunicazione
            out = new DataOutputStream(msocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(msocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Errore durante l'istanza del server");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return msocket;
    }


    public void calcola(){
        try{
            double x;
            double y;
            double risultato=0;
            //leggo la scelta e in base a quella eseguo le operazioni
            int scelta = in.read();

            //accetto prima i numeri
            x = in.read();

            System.out.println("x "+x);
            y = in.read();
            System.out.println("y "+y);

            switch (scelta){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Scelta: "+scelta);
                    //somma
                    risultato = x+y;


            }
            System.out.println("Risultato: "+risultato);

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Server myServer = new Server();
        myServer.attendi();
        myServer.calcola();
    }
}
```

CLIENT

```
    package calcolatrice;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client{
    Socket socket;
    protected int porta = 1122;
    String nomeServer = "localhost";
    //stream per comunicare
    DataOutputStream out;
    BufferedReader in;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Socket connetti(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Client avviato..");
            //creo il socket per connettermi al server
            socket = new Socket(nomeServer, porta);
            System.out.println("Client connesso con successo al server ' "+nomeServer+" ' sulla porta: "+porta);
            //inizializzo gli stream per consentire la comunicazione
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Errore, impossibile connettersi");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return socket;

    }

    //menu per scelta operazioni
    private void menu(){
        try{
            System.out.println("---Calcolatrice---");
            System.out.println("[1.Somma \t 2.Differenza \t 3.Moltiplicazione \t 4.Divisione]");
            System.out.println("0.ESCI");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Errore");
        }


    }

    //funzione per comunicare
    public void comunica(){
        try {
            int scelta=0;
            //do{
                menu();
                System.out.println("Inserire operazione ");
                scelta = input.nextInt();
                //invio la scelta al server
                //out.writeByte(scelta);
                out.write(scelta);

                //Inserisco i numeri e li spedisco al server
                System.out.println("Inserisci primo numero.");
                double x = input.nextDouble();
                out.writeDouble(x);

                System.out.println("Inserisci secondo numero.");
                double y = input.nextDouble();
                out.writeDouble(y);

            //}
            //while(scelta != 0);
        }catch (IOException e){

        }


    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Client myClient = new Client();
        myClient.connetti();
        myClient.comunica();


    }
}
```

Comment: First thing to understand when programming: you should separate concerns. The code that parses numbers and computes results ... has absolutely no need to know anything about sockets, streams; and so on. Meaning: first write code that takes input (of the form that you later want to send via sockets) and computes output based on that input. When all of that works well, and is fully tested (you should use unit tests for that); then you can go one step further and add the client/server part. It is easier to solve puzzles with 10 pieces, than solving one with 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code uses a `BufferedReader` which I think might be the cause of the problem. If you replace this with a `DataInputStream`, you will be able to call `readInt()` and `readDouble()` methods.

Replace `BufferedReader in;` with `DataInputStream in;`. It can be constructed in a similar way to the existing code using:

`in = new DataInputStream(msocket.getInputStream());`

Then replace all calls to `in.read()` with either `in.readInt()` or `in.readDouble()` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing the DataOutputStream object (out) then I added the following line to the comunica() method:

```
System.out.println(x + "," + y);
```

Re-running your code I got the output:

> Client avviato..
>
> Client connesso con successo al server ' localhost ' sulla porta: 1122
>
> ---Calcolatrice---
>
> [1.Somma    2.Differenza    3.Moltiplicazione   4.Divisione]
> 0.ESCI
>
> Inserire operazione
>
> 1
>
> Inserisci primo numero.
>
> 2
>
> Inserisci secondo numero.
>
> 3
>
> 2.0,3.0

Your code is reading in the numbers OK.

Comment: How it is supposed to work without the DataOutputStream?

Comment: I've added another suggestion. If that works OK, I'll delete this answer.